# MySQL 5.7: Understanding SIGINT, KILL, and DECLARE HANDLER

Tags: mysql-5.7

I'm reading the documentation for MySQL 5.7 and I would like to know how to write a Stored Procedure that gracefully terminates when requested by the user.

It seems like CTRL-C or SIGINT only kills the statements on the client end, and the statements continue to execute server side.

How does the KILL command affect a stored procedure that is mid-transaction?
Does it trigger the DECLARE HANDLER? If so, with what SQLSTATE?

Thank you!